# zend_paginator is not accepting values set from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

i am using zend framework + smarty, in my search page i have added paginator for 10 rows per page. but as i am going next paginator is not accepting set values.
In my controller :

```
 $this->view->prev_search_txt = $key;
```

and in paginator.tpl file passing argument as

```
    {if (isset($this->next))} 
       <a title="Next" rel="next" class="paginator-next" href="{$this->url(['page' => $next,'search_txt'=>$prev_search_txt])}">Next</a>
    {else}
    <span class="paginator-next">Next</span>
    {/if}
```

but it is not taking `prev_search_txt` value in next page link.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're calling paginationControl view helper somewhere like this

```
echo $this->paginationControl($paginator, 'Sliding', 'paginator.tpl');
```

pass the variable you need as the 4th param like

```
echo $this->paginationControl($paginator, 'Sliding', 'paginator.tpl',
     array('prev_search_txt' => $this->prev_search_txt));
```

Comment: no i am calling paginator only . this values are set in controller

Comment: put how are you passing the paginator object to the view.